# VBA matching principle

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having this situation:
Given :

```
Plant A - Plant B ( Route 1)
Plant B - Plant C ( Route 2)
Plant C - Plant D ( Route 3)
Plant D - Customer ( Final route)
```

of which:

```
Plant A ( Starting plant) and Plant D ( ending plant before the    customer) are determined
- Plant B , Plant C and Customer are unknown ( also do not need to know)
- Logic: the Ending Plant of 1 route will be the starting plant of the next route ( exp: in route 1, Plant B is the destination plant.    In route 2, Plant B will be the Origin Plant)
```

Base on the logic above, I want to write a code in VBA which allows me to track the entire route from Plant A to the Customer, any route that falls out of this logic needs to be detected by giving an error message.

For example :

```
Plant A - Plant B ( Route 1)
Plant B - Plant C ( Route 2)
Plant E - Plant D ( Route 3)
Plant D - Customer ( Final route)
```

In this example, we can see that Route 2 and Route 3 do not follow the logic above, this error should be pointed out by VBA.
an anyone please give me some advises in this case? Thank you very much!

Comment: We need to know how your data is set up. Is it in a table in as single sheet? A DB? Please expand. Also, it would definitely improve your question if you were to share any VBA attempts you made

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why Route 2 is wrong? It starts where Route 1 finished...

Comment: Hi Tim Stack, it is data from different tables being pulled from ECC. I am not familiar with VBA so I am still searching and learning for experience. Thank you

Comment: Hi Foxfire, if you look at the example number 2, you will see in route 2 the inventory being shipped from Plant B to Plant C ( as destination plant ), for route 3, it should be shipped from Plant C ( now as Origin Plant) to Plant D and so on. However, Plant E shows up in the track from no where and I t should not be the case.

Comment: @tienbui you are not getting answers because we can't see how your data is set up. *"it is data from different tables"* is too vague. A visual representation would be of great help